# Erro ao publicar projeto no Github pelo Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

estou tentando compartilhar um projeto que tenho no Android Studio com o git mas ele sempre me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Successfully created project 'nome' on GitHub, but initial push failed: Could not read from remote repository.
```

procurando na internet, vi o pessoal falando para ir em **Configuração -> Controle de versão -> git -> ssh** e selecionar nativo, porém mesmo fazendo isso ele apresenta o mesmo erro.

existe outra solução?

Comment: O repositório é criado com sucesso no seu github? Se não, não será um problema de acesso com a sua chave SSH ou senha errada? Tente criar manualmente o repositório de dar push com "git init" e "git push origin master" para verificar se esses erros ainda ocorrem (o Android Studio conseguirá sincronizar depois).

Comment: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: O repositório é criado com sucesso no meu github, porém ele é criado vazio. Eu criei um token com acesso irrestrito a conta, e mesmo assim continua com erro. Vou tentar criar manualmente como você me indicou.